# How do I use regex to take all numbers followed by the first digit of the identifier of a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string that needs to be converted to the following:

```
3 Apples 5 Bananas 7 Oranges ===> 3A 5B 7O

3 Apple(s) 5 Banana(s) 7 Oranges, 19 Cherries ===> 3A 5B 7O 19C
```

Comment: To match, it looks like Find `(\d+)\s+([A-Z])\S*` and replace with `$1$2` https://regex101.com/r/SaNNfo/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string.replace(/(\d+)\s(\w)\S*/g,'$1$2')
```

both variants would work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function convert(s) {
    return s.replace(/(\d+)\s*([A-Z])\D*?(\s|$)/ig, '$1$2$3');
}

convert('3 Apples 5 Bananas 7 Oranges');                  // returns '3A 5B 7O'
convert('3 Apple(s) 5 Banana(s) 7 Oranges, 19 Cherries'); // returns '3A 5B 7O 19C'
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET(C#) you can use System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex class:

```
        Regex re = new Regex(@"([\d]*)\sApples?\s([\d]*)\sBananas?\s([\d]*)\sOranges?");
        Match m = re.Match("3 Apple 5 Banana 7 Orange");
        string res = string.Format("{0}A {1}B {2}O", m.Groups[1], m.Groups[2], m.Groups[3]);
```

Comment: Where are the cherries? I think you misinterpreted where the letters come from (to be honest - it's not a good question)

Comment: @KingKongFrog: It's not a good question when you don't completely define the problem - which you don't. You expect others to interpret it for you. Then you show zero effort at tackling the problem. It appears you just expect other people to write your code for you (while also making up the requirements because you didn't bother to include them).